# Twilio conference connection delay

Tags: node.js, twilio, twilio-api

I'm using Twilio to set up an inbound call center. I'm using SIP softphones as my endpoints. I have virtually everything working the way I want it, but there is major issue when trying to start a "Conference" to one of my sip endpoints.

The service rep does not hear the callers words until about 7 seconds into the call. The inbound caller can hear the service rep just fine. This is only a problem with the "Conference." The code below also illustrates a direct connection via dialing an extension where the connection delay does not occur at all.

```js
// Inbound Call to Twilio Number
routes.post('/twilio/phone/inbound', (req, res) => {
  const twilioVoice = new VoiceResponse();
  const gather = twilioVoice.gather({
    action: '/twilio/phone/enqueue',
    numDigits: 3,
    timeout: 2
  });
  gather.say('For general inquiries, press 1. If you know the extension of the person you are trying to reach, please enter it now.', {
    loop: 5
  });
  twilioVoice.say('Sorry, I did not get a response. Good bye.');
  twilioVoice.hangup();
  res.type('text/xml');
  res.send(twilioVoice.toString());
});

// Second endpoint to process response from above
routes.post('/twilio/phone/enqueue', (req, res) => {
  var pressedKeys = req.body.Digits;
  var twilioVoice = new VoiceResponse();
  if (pressedKeys.length === 3) {
    console.log("Direct call via extension.")
    twilioVoice.say(`Please hold while we attempt to connect you to extension`);
    twilioVoice.dial().sip('sip:employee@businessname.sip.us1.twilio.com');
    // Once connected, both parties can hear each other immediately.
    res.send(twilioVoice.toString());
  } else {
    twilioVoice.enqueue({
      workflowSid: process.env.WORKFLOW_SID,
    });
    res.type('text/xml');
    res.send(twilioVoice.toString());
  }
});


// Workflow AssignmentCallbackUrl
routes.post('/twilio/phone/assignworker', (req, res) => {
  res.type('application/json');
  // The service rep does not hear the callers words until about 7 seconds into the call
  res.send({
    instruction: "conference",
    to: "sip:employee@businessname.sip.us1.twilio.com"
  });
});
```

Comment: It looks like you have everything setup as you would expect. For issues with the call itself I'd recommend contacting [Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) and supplying some Call SIDs where this happened so that the call can be investigated.